# Difference between float(2,2) and float() in mysql

Tags: mysql, floating-point

I created a table in MySQL with a column of type float(2,2) and inserted value 10 into the same, but I found that the value stored is 0.99.

What is the reason behind this ? If we use a column of type float(m, n) in MySQL where 'm' and 'n' are integers, then what should I watch out for when storing values in this column ?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

[`float(2,2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) means "use two digits, of which two are used after the decimal point".

Hence, you can go from -0.99 to 0.99. You can't insert 10 into this column, you'd need atleast two digits before the comma (so float(4,2) or float(2,0)).

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up
>   to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal
>   point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like
>   -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate
>   result is 999.0001.

Answer (score 19):

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to **M digits in total**, of which **D digits may be after the decimal point**.

Comment: @Francis: welcome to stackoverflow! Your answer was correct, if you find the right mix between 'answering the actual question', 'explaining the general principle', 'explaining where to find it in the documentation' and 'linking to the documentation', you are likely to get more upvotes for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

In MySql, There are data type like FLOAT(M,D).Where D is the
number of decimals and M is the total number of digits (including
decimals).Decimal precision can go to 24 places for a FLOAT and M range 1 to 65.
If syntax is FLOAT(2,2), then there have only two decimal place and no place to real number.So you want to add 10 you can use like FLOAT(5,2).

Answer (score 3):

float(M,D) this keeping in mind here M=max. no. of digit allowed(range 1 to 65), D=no. of digits after the decimal point.
so cany you change it float(5,2). so float(2,2) does not satisfiy your need to enter no.10

Answer (score 2):

While the above answers are correct, float(2, 2) is not advisable to use and avoiding this type of declaration is the best practice. In FLOAT(M,D), (M,D) means that values can be stored with up to M total digits, where D can be after the decimal. Numbers will be rounded twice or truncated; this will cause more trouble than benefit. The reason is that floating point numbers are processed by CPU as approximate numbers and not exact values. If (M,D) type of declaration is desired then DECIMAL(M,D) data type should be used instead.

This is a citation from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the nonstandard FLOAT(M,D) and DOUBLE(M,D) syntax is deprecated and you should expect support for it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.