# using DBI to upload float numbers to MySql

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have the followng string `$x='20.400'` and want to upload it using DBI to float column on mysql. When I update this value with DBI on the DB it look `20.4` how can I keep the last zeros

Here are my query :

```
my $sql='update x set value=?';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute($x);
```

worth to mention if I update by hand `update x set value='20.400'` it works ok

Comment: You do understand that `20.400` and `20.4` are two different representations of the same value, right? And if you do, how'd you expect MySQL to store the preferred presentation when you told it to store _value_ (in `FLOAT` column)?

Comment: What do you get if you do `$x = 20.400`?

Comment: Why do you want to store meaningless zeroes?

Comment: Well, 20.400 and 20.4 are different numbers to scientists since they have a different number of significant figures. :)

Answer (score 1):

The mysql server is storing floating numbers without trailing zeros by default.

What kind of float are you using? [Difference between float(2,2) and float() in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979912/difference-between-float3-2-and-float-in-mysql)

If you are not using float(m,d) format then try to use that so the mysql client is going to produce trailing zeros for you but beaware that mysql is going to round your numbers!

Otherwise use float and sprintf in your perl program when you display the result.